# do while pattern of output must be the same as example

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

im wondering,

is it posible to convert this `for loop` inside `for loop` to a `do while loop`?

here is the code:

```
int i, j, rows;

printf("Enter number of rows: ");
scanf("%d",&rows);

for(i=1; i<=rows; ++i)
{
    for(j=1; j<=i; ++j)
    {
        printf("* ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

here is what i've tried:

```
    int i, j, rows;

    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    i=1;
    j=1;

do {

    printf("* ");
    i<=rows;
    ++i;
    ++j;

} while (j<=i);

    printf("\n");

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

tried everything i could but no luck. 
by the way im trying to do a star pattern using a `do while loop` any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Why? A loop is a loop. If a `for` loop makes sense, use a `for` loop. You'll get a `do while` loop that acts like a `for` loop anyway.

Comment: but i need to follow a rule. it says i need to use do while loop instead of for loop

Answer (score 1):

in your code you have only one `do while` loop you should use two nested `do while`   loop in order to achieve your goal:

```
    i=1;
    j=1;
do {
   do {   
    printf("* ");
    ++j;     
   } while (j<=i);

    printf("\n");
    i++;
    j=1;
} while(i <= rows);
```

test program:
https://ideone.com/QhN3l4